# library issue related to conda environment not active

Tags: anaconda

When I try to activate my conda environment. I receive the following error:

```
conda create --name env_test python=3.9.7 
conda activate env_test
source $IDPROOT/bin/activate
Could not find conda environment: libigdrcl.so
```

I am using conda version 22.11.1

Any suggestions on how to resolve ?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow").  As written, your question lacks sufficient details for someone to provide an answer.  Please explain your environment more thoroughly, what anaconda environments exist?  What is the context from which your command is being executed.  Without this information, any answer is purely conjecture on our part.

Comment: `conda activate` is the way; why is a `source activate` being done? That is more for `virtualenv` style environments.

Comment: I agree the statement ```conda activate env_test``` should be sufficient to activate the env_test environment.  What are you trying to achieve beyond activating the env_test environment?